# Error in my html?

Tags: html

I made my first attempt here to create my own webpage.. But what can be the error in the code i wrote here?

```
<div align=center>
<a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Twitter','','icons/twitter.png',1)"><img src="icons/twittergrey.png" alt="Twitter" name="Twitter" width="48" height="48" border="0" id="Twitter" /> </a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/StaticArc" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Facebook','','icons/facebook.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="icons/facebookgrey.png" alt="Facebook" name="Facebook" width="48" height="48" border="0" id="Facebook" /> </a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('YouTube','','icons/youtube.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="icons/youtubegrey.png" alt="YouTube" name="YouTube" width="48" height="48" border="0" id="YouTube" /> </a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('RSS','','icons/rss.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="icons/rssgrey.png" alt="RSS" name="RSS" width="48" height="48" border="0" id="RSS" /> </a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Android Market','','icons/android.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="icons/androidgrey.png" alt="Android Market" name="Android Market" width="48" height="48" border="0" id="Android Market" /></a>
<a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Twitter','','icons/twitter.png',1)">
<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/StaticArcUK" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Twitter','','icons/twitter.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('YouTube','','icons/youtube.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('YouTube','','icons/youtube.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()">
<a href="#" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('YouTube','','icons/youtube.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"></a>
```

Sorry i got this loong lines here.. Dunno how i could make it look like a list..

Comment: You need to understand when posting questions that it is your responsibility (if you want valuable feedback instead of down votes) to articulate your question succinctly and clearly. Go back through and read your question ... could you even determine what the question is? If your question is, "Help, I don't know what I did wrong, can someone fix it?" Then this is the wrong place for you.

Comment: What did you even try to accomplish? What error did you get? What shall the functions in your code do? Where did you get this HTML code from?

Comment: Sorry.. I know its bad question but i couldn't find why this wont work @MatthewCox

Comment: you didn't say what you expected to see and what you saw instead... It's not just a bad question, it's not even a question. It's a "please fix it for me" request.

Comment: I would advise you to learn how to add an event listener to your elements via js.  At present all your `onmouseover=`s really confuse the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's only two problems I can see, the first is that the center should be in speech marks, so it should look like `="center"`. Secondly you need to add `</div>` at the end... Should work then :D

Comment: the OP has an ending div tag in there.

Comment: @Joseph Where? I don't seem to see it

Comment: whoa... now that I look for it I can't fint it either O_o...... It must have been inserted by jsFiddle when I was working on it. -__-  Sorry about that.

Comment: I tried to put center in side "" and i added the </div> and its now working thanks @iNinjaDJ

Answer (score 1):

You have an embedded anchor tag in an anchor tag (may cause problems) you also are missing two ending anchor tags and an ending div tag as noted by others.

Your markup is really confusing though XD

cleaned up (a little) version of your markup
http://jsfiddle.net/MZge2/1

Answer (score 1):

After breaking your lines, a couple of your anchors are missing the `</a>` on them, which I'm sure is going to be causing some problems for you.

Also, `align="center"` is deprecated. Use `style="text-align: center"` instead.

P.S. You really shouldn't write your code all on one line like that (at least hopefully you aren't). All that will cause is problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Close

```
<div align=center>  with  </div>
<div align=center>  Should be    <div align="center">
```